Grading between house and patio
Installing a 60’x20’ concrete patio that runs the length of my house and attached garage. My furnace inlet/out pipes are located on that side of the house, so I was thinking of starting the patio 3’ off the house to prevent the HVAC pipes from being bumped into by drunk guests. My question: how would I properly grade the 3’ between the house and patio? Was thinking I could fill that area with river rock, and water would flow through the rock into the sand beneath the concrete away from the house. Would this work, or do I need to add back fill sloping towards the patio before installing the rock?

how is your house constructed: basement , pier and beam , slab on grade?  what is the hazard?  you reckon 3' is enough?  That sounds a bit like a french drain, why not go the whole way?  some drawings would probably help.

House has a full basement with perimeter tile. My only concern with the layout is that I’m  basically creating a 3’ wide channel that may not drain away from the house as easily as it did before the patio was installed. My drain tile is below this area so probably not a huge concern.  Just figured I’d give it some thought before putting patio in.

Or you could simply put a barrier around your HVAC pipes...

Backfill to create your slope, put landscaping fabric down to prevent weeds and cover with your river rock.
